# General expression for a 2-form in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: analysis, differential-forms

Let $A$ open in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, $u=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}e_{i}$ and $v=\sum_{i=1}^{n}b_{i}e_{i}$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, where $\{e_{1},\dots,e_{n}\}$ denote the usual basis for $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. 
How can I write the general expression for a 2-form $\omega(p,u,v)$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$?

I know that $$\omega\left(p,\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}e_{i},\sum_{i=1}^{n}b_{i}e_{i}\right)=\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}a_{i}b_{j}\omega\left(p,e_{i},e_{j}\right).$$
But $\omega(p,e_{i},e_{i})=0$ and $\omega(p,e_{i},e_{j})=-\omega(p,e_{j},e_{j})$. I'm looking for a way to write this as a combination of determinants. Can I?

Comment: The answer for your last answer is not, you can't. A determinant is an $n$-form, so you would need mlre vectors. And the more general expression you can achieve is to say that $\omega(p,e_i,e_j)=\omega_{ij}$ for certain (real) coefficients $\omega_{ij}$.

Comment: take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2808797/give-a-formula-for-the-pairing-%CE%B1%E2%88%A7%CE%B2-v%E2%8A%97w-in-terms-of-the-pairings-of-vectors-and/2810564#2810564 it might help